# No programmers available for this board - Programming ESP32 Cam with Ardunio IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, programmer, camera

This is my first time working with ESP32 Cam boards.
I have followed the instructions as given in this site https://technoreview85.com/how-to-program-esp-32-cam-using-arduino-uno-board/
However my IDE doesn't display any programmers for this board.

[image: Problem!]

Couldn't find any details about this in google. I just want to know how I could fix this problem(i.e. get the programmers listed).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you the older version of Arduino IDE. 1.8.12 also worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no programmers for ESP32. It only accepts Serial upload over bootloader.

Versions of IDE before 1.8.13 displayed programmers for all board support packages, that is why a programmer could be selected. Now only programmers for package of the selected board are available. But programmers are used only with the "Burn bootloader" or "Upload with programmer" commands, not with standard Serial upload over bootloader.

Answer (score 3):

The older version of Arduino IDE. 1.8.12 worked.